# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {..}

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

In the below code im trying invoke a fragment from and activity

### MainActivity

```
public class WalletActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
private Button mBankAccount;
private Button mCreditCard;
private Button mPassport;
private Button mLicence;
private Button mIdentity;
private Button mWifiRouter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wallet);

    mBankAccount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bank_account);
    mBankAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = BankAccountListActivity.newIntent(WalletActivity.this);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    mIdentity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.identity);
    mIdentity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = IndentityListActivity.newIntent(WalletActivity.this);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**Note:-** look at the Identity part of the code

### RecyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:id="@+id/identity_recycler_view"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

### IdentityActivity

```
public class IndentityListActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity
{
public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext) {
    Intent i = new Intent(packageContext,     IndentityListActivity.class);
    return i;
}

@Override
protected Fragment createFragment() {
    return new IdentityListFragment();
}}
```

### Identity Fragment

```
public class IdentityListFragment extends Fragment
{
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private IdentityAdapter mIdentityAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //Wiring recycler view
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.identity_list_fragment, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.identity_recycler_view);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    updateUI();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    updateUI();
}

private class IdentityHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private Identity mIdentity;
    private TextView mTitleTextView;

    public IdentityHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        mTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_identity_title_text_view);
    }

    //binds the title,date and check box
    public void bindIdentity(Identity identity)
    {
        mIdentity = identity;

        mTitleTextView.setText(mIdentity.getIdentity());

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = IdentityPagerActivity.newIntent(getActivity(), mIdentity.getUUID());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

private class IdentityAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<IdentityHolder>
{
    private List<Identity> mIdentities;

    public IdentityAdapter (List<Identity> identities )
    {
        mIdentities = identities ;
    }

    //This method is called to create a view
    @Override
    public IdentityHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View view = layoutInflater
                .inflate(R.layout.identity_list_fragment, parent, false);

        return new IdentityHolder(view);
    }


    //binds them together
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(IdentityHolder holder, int position)
    {
        Identity identity = mIdentities.get(position);
        holder.bindIdentity(identity);
    }

    private void setIdentities (List<Identity> identities)
    {
        mIdentities = identities;
    }

    //RecycleView Calls this method to get the size of mCrimes
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mIdentities.size();
    }
}

public void updateUI()
{
    WalletIdentity walletIdentity = WalletIdentity.get(getActivity());
    List<Identity> identities = walletIdentity.getIdentity();

    if (mIdentityAdapter == null)
    {
        mIdentityAdapter = new IdentityAdapter(identities);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mIdentityAdapter);
    }
    else
    {
        mIdentityAdapter.setIdentities(identities);
        mIdentityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_crime_list, menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.menu_item_new_crime:
            Identity identity = new Identity();
            WalletIdentity.get(getActivity()).addIdentity(identity);
            Intent intent = IdentityPagerActivity
                    .newIntent(getActivity(), identity.getUUID());
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;


        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}}
```

**Note:-**I have implemented almost same code in BankAccount it is working fine

## Error Message

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.example.kamalnrf.wallet, PID: 2456
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kamalnrf.wallet/com.example.kamalnrf.wallet.Controllers.IdentityControllers.IndentityListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.example.kamalnrf.wallet.Controllers.IdentityControllers.IdentityListFragment.onCreateView(IdentityListFragment.java:45)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:339)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:602)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6088)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
```

im getting the above message when im clicking the identity button...

Please let me if you need any additional data

Answer (score 2):

Check if the identity_recycler_view is in the identity_list_fragment layout file

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.identity_list_fragment, container, false);

mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view
        .findViewById(R.id.identity_recycler_view);
```

Exception is happening here

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

**Cause**

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
>   virtual method 'void
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                              at
>   com.example.kamalnrf.wallet.Controllers.IdentityControllers.IdentityListFragment.onCreateView(IdentityListFragment.java:45)

Logcat says you are trying to set LayoutManager on `null` RecyclerView  object

**Possible Solution**

look inside your `identity_list_fragment.xml`it  must contain recycler view with id `identity_recycler_view`